# I am getting file not found when doing a cUrl to Google translate API

Tags: php, google-translate

Please tell me what I am missing here? I keep getting error 404, file not found

```
    $apiKey = "MY-KEY-IS-HERE";
    $apiUri = "https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2";

    $text = "Hello world";
    $source = "EN";
    $target = "NL";

    if (!$target || !$text) {
        echo "Noting to translate";
    } else {
        $fields = array(
            "key" => $apiKey,
            "source" => $source,
            "target" => $target,
            "q" => $text
        );
        $fieldsString = "";
        foreach($fields as $key=>$value) {
            $fieldsString .= $key . '=' . $value . '&';
        }
        rtrim($fieldsString, '&');
        echo $fieldsString;

        $handle = curl_init($apiUri);
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, $apiUri);
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fieldsString);
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Length: ' . strlen($fieldsString)));
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $response = curl_exec($handle);

        $responseCode = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        if($responseCode != 200) {
            echo 'Fetching translation failed! Server response code: ' . $responseCode . '<br>';
            echo $response;
        }
        else {
            echo $response;
        }
        curl_close($handle);
```

When I put at CURL_POSTFIELDS the $string array, nothing changes. Also tried adding a ? mark in the URI or added a trailing slash. Keep getting the same errors. For testing I also removed the lines:

```
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fieldsString);
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Length: ' . strlen($fieldsString)));
```

And then got an error saying that length is missing in the headers. Which would say it reaches the api correctly..???

GOT IT TO WORK LIKE THIS:

```
    $apiKey = "MY-KEY-IS-HERE";
    $apiUri = "https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2";

    $text = "Hello world";
    $source = "EN";
    $target = "NL";

    if (!$target || !$text) {
        echo "Noting to translate";
        exit;
    } else {
        $fields = array(
            "key" => $apiKey,
            "source" => $source,
            "target" => $target,
            "q" => $text
        );
        $handle = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, $apiUri);
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-HTTP-Method-Override: GET"));
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $response = curl_exec($handle);

        $responseDecoded = json_decode($response, true);

        $responseCode = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        if($responseCode != 200) {
            echo 'Fetching translation failed! Server response code: ' . $responseCode . '<br>';
            echo $response;
        }
        else {
            echo $responseDecoded['data']['translations'][0]['translatedText'];
        }
        curl_close($handle);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You waste a lot of time doing stuff that CURL can do for you automatically, and far more reliably:

```
    $handle = curl_init($apiUri);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, $apiUri);  // redundant
```

You've already set the URI via curl_init(), there's NO point in setting it yet again.

Then you also build your own post body, set content-length, blah blah blah. Skip all of that. All you need is

```
    $fields = array(
        "key" => $apiKey,
        "source" => $source,
        "target" => $target,
        "q" => $text // note LACK of urlencode here
    );
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
```

CURL will happily take your array and transform it as necessary, and set whatever appropriate headers as well.

Comment: I did all you suggested, but still am getting 404 Not Found